# Android: NullPointerException for new Intent for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm kinda stuck with this problem on android. I created a maps API application, with a custom overlay and every time I try to click an overlay and start an intent (google maps) the thing crashes:

possibly relevant code:

```
threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
at com.jcfrei.chparking.funtionality.startgmapsnav(funtionality.java:16)
 at com.jcfrei.chparking.ParkingOverlay.onTap(ParkingOverlay.java:91)
 at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
 at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
 at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:346)
 at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:506)
 at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:628)
 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and

```
 public class funtionality extends Activity {


   public void startgmapsnav (String lat, String lon) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:38.899533,-77.036476"));
         startActivity(myIntent);

}

 }
```

inside Overlay

```
    @Override
protected boolean onTap(int index)  {
  //OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);


  funtionality lm = new funtionality();

  lm.startgmapsnav(lat, lon);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What tutorial did you get

```
 funtionality lm = new funtionality();

  lm.startgmapsnav(lat, lon);
```

from?

You never, ever, ever, call `new` on a class that extends `Activity`. Ever. Period.

Comment: that's my code. But that class doesnt extend Activity - just  funtionality does. - However, should it extend Activity? without calling new of course.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what the problem is...there are data structures the Android runtime expects and aren't set if the activity isn't setup correctly.

Comment: @johnny, right.  You NEVER instantiate an `Activity` subclass directly which is exactly what you're doing.  You need to restructure your code.  For starts, I'd just pull the code out of `startgmapsnav` and put it in where you call `new` and try it like that first.  There's no need to have an additional activity there.  If you want to abstract it away later you can, but remove as many variables as possible to get it working.

Comment: thanks for all the advice! I just migrated the whole Overlay class with the ontap event into the main Activity and now it works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

My best guess it that `Uri.parse("geo:38.899533,-77.036476")` is failing, and returning null.  Did you verify that this creates the expected Uri?

Comment: no, I copied this from a tutorial - I'll try a different string

Comment: So?  Did you test it?  And make sure that it is giving you the right thing?

Comment: ok, just tried it with `"http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html"` and it throws the same error